# Unable to add double digits in a calculator. Can only add single digit numbers

Tags: javascript

Like the title says. When I put single digit numbers, it works good but when I try to put bigger numbers like two digit numbers, it doesn't work and I have no idea why. It seems like it reads only second digit of a second number, for example: 50 + 55(it's read as a 5) so the result is 55. Same with 3 digits number, it only reads a third digit in the second number.

```js
const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('.output');
calcDisplay.textContent = '0'

let num2 = ''

const add = (a, b) =>  a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) =>  a - b;
const multiply = (a, b) =>  a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => a / b;

//assigning calculator functions to operators' buttons //
  const buttonOperation = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {
  operator.addEventListener('click', () => {
  operator.classList.add('isDepressed')
  
    switch(operator) {
      case(operator.dataset.action === 'add'):
        return add(a, b)
       
      case(operator.dataset.action  === 'substract'):
        return subtract(a, b)

      case(operator.dataset.action  === 'multiply'):
        return multiply(a, b)

      case(operator.dataset.action  === 'divide'):
        return divide(a, b)
        
    }  

   num2 = calcDisplay.textContent
  }) 
});

 //an event that make digits appear on the display // 
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButton').forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  removeClass();
  num1 = button.textContent;
  displayedNum = calcDisplay.textContent;

    if (displayedNum === '0') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = num1;
  } else if (displayedNum === num2) {
      calcDisplay.textContent = num1
  } else  {
      calcDisplay.textContent = displayedNum + num1
  }
  
  });

});


const buttonEquals = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals');
buttonEquals.addEventListener('click', () => {
document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {
  if(operator.dataset.action === 'add') {
    calcDisplay.textContent = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)
   }
});
});





// Clears the whole display with one click //
const buttonClear = document.querySelector('.keyButtonClear');
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  calcDisplay.textContent = '0'
  // I will fill up the rest of the code here when I get done with the rest //
  
});

// Deletes a single number when you click a button //
function deleteInput() {
  const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonDelete')
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calcDisplay.textContent = calcDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);

  });
}
deleteInput()

//removes a selection of a operator after a second number is clicked //
function removeClass () {
  buttonRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(button => {
  button.classList.remove('isDepressed')

  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
        <body>
          <div class="calcContainer">

            
            <div class="buttons">
              <div class="output">
              </div>
              <button class="keyButton">7</button>
              <button class="keyButton">8</button>
              <button class="keyButton">9</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "SignChange" >+/-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonDelete">DEL</button>

              <button class="keyButton">4</button>
              <button class="keyButton">5</button>
              <button class="keyButton">6</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="multiply">X</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="divide">%</button>

              <button class="keyButton">1</button>
              <button class="keyButton">2</button>
              <button class="keyButton">3</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "substract">-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonEquals">=</button>

              <button class="keyButtonClear">C</button>
              <button class="keyButton">0</button>
              <button class="keyButton">.</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "add">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>

            <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following solves your problem:

```js
//...

const buttonEquals = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals');
buttonEquals.addEventListener('click', () => {

  // ADD THIS:
  num1 = calcDisplay.textContent;

  document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(operator => {
    if(operator.dataset.action === 'add') {
      calcDisplay.textContent = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)
    } 
  });
});

//...
```

You have to set `num1` to the value in the display. Otherwise, it uses the last number typed.

Comment: I was trying to do that but I was putting num1 = calcDisplay.textContent; after document.querySelectorAll lmao. It's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by Beni Trainor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72770041/18545859) is the answer you're looking for. However, the following calculator I wrote, based on your calculator, may be of some use to you. It allows for more complex operations with multiple numbers at a time. This may be useful to you, but I'm glad that [Beni Trainor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72770041/18545859) was sufficient for your needs!

```js
// These are the characters which are allowed in the display.
var allowed = /[0-9()*/+\-.]/g;

// This evaluates a string as an equation according to the allowed characters above.
function solve(equation) {
 try {
  if(equation == '') {
   return '';
  }
  return Function('return Number('+equation.match(allowed).join('')+');')();
 } catch {
  return 'Error';
 }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

 // Create a variable containing the display element for ease of reference.
 var display = document.querySelector('.calculator .display');

 // Add scrolling to the display with a smooth scroll behavior.
 display.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
   this.scrollBy((event.deltaY/Math.abs(event.deltaY))*2, 0);
   i+= 2;
   if(i >= Math.abs(event.deltaY)) {
    clearInterval(interval);
   }
  }, 1);
 });

 // Allow character buttons to input their character to the display.
 document.querySelectorAll('.calculator .character').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
   display.value+= this.innerText;
   // This ensures that the display only contains allowed characters.
   display.value = display.value.match(allowed).join('');
   display.scrollTo(display.scrollWidth, 0);
  });
 });

 // Allow the delete action key to delete characters from the display.
 document.querySelector('.calculator .delete').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // This ensures that the display only contains allowed characters.
  try {
   display.value = display.value.slice(0, -1).match(allowed).join('');
  } catch {
   display.value = '';
  }
  display.scrollTo(display.scrollWidth, 0);
 });

 // Allow the submit action key to calculate the user's equation.
 document.querySelector('.calculator .submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var solution = solve(display.value);

  // YOUR CODE GOES HERE TO STORE OR OTHERWISE PROCESS THE SOLUTION

  display.value = solution;
 });

 // Allow the clear action key to clear the display.
 document.querySelector('.calculator .clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
  display.value = '';
 });

});
```

```css
body, body :not(head) {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: inherit;
}

.calculator {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.display {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 padding: 1ch;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: right;
}

button {
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 background-color: white;
}

button:hover:not(:active) {
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

button.number {
 border: 1px dotted lightgray;
}

button.operator {
 border: 1px dashed black;
}

button.action {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='calculator'>
   <input class='display' disabled />
   <button class='character number'>7</button>
   <button class='character number'>8</button>
   <button class='character number'>9</button>
   <button class='character operator'>(</button>
   <button class='character operator'>)</button>
   <button class='character number'>4</button>
   <button class='character number'>5</button>
   <button class='character number'>6</button>
   <button class='character operator'>*</button>
   <button class='character operator'>/</button>
   <button class='character number'>1</button>
   <button class='character number'>2</button>
   <button class='character number'>3</button>
   <button class='character operator'>+</button>
   <button class='character operator'>-</button>
   <button class='action delete'>&#9249;</button>
   <button class='character number'>0</button>
   <button class='character operator'>.</button>
   <button class='action submit'>=</button>
   <button class='action clear'>C</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```